# Bash script not sleeping when running scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, sleep

I have several bash scripts that I need to run in parallel. However, they are memory hogs so I would like to stagger each of them by 30 seconds but still run in parallel. For example:

```
hourr=($(seq 0 1 23))

for q in "${hourr[@]}";
do;
echo $q; sleep 10;
done
```

This waits 10 seconds and then outputs a number, sequentially, from 0 to 23. However, when I try to do this with my scripts:

```
hourr=($(seq 0 1 23))
input1="20160101"; 
input2="10"; #(Note: These are inputs to each of the scripts I want to run)
scriptdir="/path/to/somewhere"
for q in "${hourr[@]}"
do
if [ "${#q}" == "1" ]
then
hh=0${q}
else
hh=${q}
fi
echo $hh
( bash $scriptdir/Hour$hh.csh $input1 $input2 ; sleep 30 ) &
done
wait
echo "All done!"
```

However, all of the Hour scripts run at once (correctly, and in parallel) when the main script is executed, and does not wait the 30 seconds that I have specified to run one after the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: You put your command in background with trailing `&`, of course not wait for execute next instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did it like this?

```
#/bin/bash

input1='20160101'
input2='10' #(Note: These are inputs to each of the scripts I want to run)
scriptdir='/path/to/somewhere'
for q in {00..23}
do
    hh="${q}"
    echo "$hh"
    ( bash "$scriptdir/Hour$hh.csh" "$input1" "$input2" ) &
    sleep 30
done
wait
echo "All done!"
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, the `&` is causing your `sleep` to also be executed in the background and therefore your script will not wait for it to finish before moving to the next iteration of the loop.  Also your `hourr` array is unnecessary

Comment: Perfect. Of course it was something simple!